# Absolute URL in html email using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Using Django, I am sending an html email that contains links but I can't get the links to work. I've tried using   `{{request.get_full_path}}` in my template, as well as `request.build_absolute_uri()` in my view. Any help would be great!

In my site, the correct url is given in the template like this, with url="/review_and_export/":

```
<a href="{url}{{request.get_full_path}}{{ publication.pk }}/?bibtex" target="_blank">BibTex</a>
```

Currently, this is my email code:

views.py

```
# for links in html email??
full_url = request.build_absolute_uri()
full_url = full_url.split("/software/", 1)[0]   #this produces just the domain, EDIT: i was missing a slash...still having issues

html_content = render_to_string(email_it, {'full_url' : full_url,....}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

email_it.html

```
{% for publication in value %}
    {% include "software/display_citations.html" with publication=publication url=full_url%}
{% endfor %}
```

display_citations.html

```
# I use full_url and request.get_full_path because get_full_path doesn't return the domain
<a href="{{full_url}}{{request.get_full_path}}{{ publication.pk }}/?bibtex" target="_blank">BibTex</a>
```

Comment: Did you set `request` in the template context? / Why don't you use `full_url` passed to the template?

Comment: full_url just produces the domain ( `http://localhost:8000/` ) and then `request.get_full_path` grabs the rest (`/software/select_citations/review_and_export/email_it/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=wHUsUMnlMiix&email_address=myEmail%40emailAddress.com`). But, that url ends up different from what I get when the link is accessed from the site itself...

Comment: do you have the `django.core.context_processors.request`

Comment: Yep, `django.core.context_processors.request` is in my settings file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by further manipulating the url in my views and then concatenating that result with the argument in my template. Thank you for your help!